# What is GSFunctionOptimizeCheck and GSFunctionSafeBuffersCheck from BinScope?

Tags: sdlc

I'm using Microsoft's BinScope to test arbitrary executables. BinScope is an SDLC compliance tool.

The tool flagged an executable for `GSFunctionOptimizeCheck` and `GSFunctionSafeBuffersCheck` (among others). I'm not familiar with either of them.

Searching returned about 10 results on the web, and 0 results on Stack Overflow. Microsoft's BinScope Help page does not mention it.

What are `GSFunctionOptimizeCheck` and `GSFunctionSafeBuffersCheck`, and what are the remediations?